# Cheap Windows laptop for browsing Internet and utility

Tags: laptop, displays

I am currently looking for a cheap Windows laptop for browsing the internet, reading emails and some "basic" task, NOTHING FANCY.

This laptop is not for myself, but actually for a person over 50 years old, who hasn't used computers very much in their life.

I think that I'll go for some "basic hardware" computer, the only things that matters are these 2:

- **The **bigger the display** is, the better it will be** (as he has a vision problem).
- **CHEAP**. By cheap, I mean under 500 Euros (something like 300/350 euros would be great, but I also don't want to buy him a really bad PC as it will be his birthday present).

I prefer to install Windows for myself, but also a computer with Windows already installed might be fine.

Comment: Does it really need Windows for that? Chromebooks could be a very viable choice for such a user.
Other than that, any laptop within your budget that has a modern Ryzen APU should be fine.
At first glance, the Lenovo IdeaPad 3 17ADA looks promising for that regard.

Comment: i mean he wanted to use word and excel  (he doesn't like opensorces suites like openoffice for some reason) so that's why i was specifying winwows.... I've heard of Chromebooks, but don't know how a "newbie"can relate with this os . What are the differences between windows and chromebooks os?

Comment: HP 15s-eq0025ns or Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IIL05 looks grea. tIf you don't need specifically a laptop, you can use an Intel NUC.

Answer (score 0):

If he doesn't need Windows, check out the ASUS CX17 Chromebook. It has a 17" screen that you can easily scale up if needed. ChromeOS is also super simple.

If Windows is needed, try the HP 17-cn0528sa. It has a 17" screen and Windows 11. The Pentium Gold will be adequate for surfing the web and running Outlook.